# Can i use unlike and "in" in one query?

Tags: mysql

i have some trouble with my query:

```
SELECT 
  * 
FROM 
  att 
WHERE 
  uid = "f6c507fe-8928-4780-8b54-819611435755" 
AND 
  item_position <> '99' 
AND 
  category IN('CAT1','CAT2');
```

The result is nothing. When I remove "item_position <> '99' AND", some items where displayed. I think the problem is the UNLIKE with IN... There a some rows with category "CAT1" and item_position "99". These rows should not be displayed.

Greetings!

Comment: Can you show some of the output when you remove the item_position check? It sounds like all your CAT1 and CAT2 data have item_position = 99, but I'm sure that must not be the case or you wouldn't have asked. Maybe seeing some of the data will help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
SELECT 
  * 
FROM 
  att 
WHERE 
  uid = "f6c507fe-8928-4780-8b54-819611435755" 
AND 
  (item_position <> '99' OR item_position IS NULL)
AND 
  category IN('CAT1','CAT2');
```

You mentioned that some rows are NULL. Annoyingly NULL values and <> tend to hate each other in logic, I recall.

Comment: You can also use `NOT item_position <=> '99'`. The spaceship operator `<=>` performs NULL-safe comparison.

Answer (score 0):

He fixed it him self in the comments, but this was what he ended up with:

```
SELECT 
  * 
FROM 
  att 
WHERE 
  uid = "f6c507fe-8928-4780-8b54-819611435755" 
AND 
  (item_position <> '99' OR item_position is NULL)
AND 
  category IN ('CAT1','CAT2');
```

Comment: thanks, but it doesn't work. When I remove "AND item_position <> '99'", then the rows where displayed...

"item_position" is NULL in many rows. Is that the problem? 

"item_position <> '99'" can't display rows with "item_position" NULL

Comment: This is equivalent to the askers original query.

Comment: Ok, it's simple...

    item_position <> '99' 

doesn't show something with item_position NULL

    SELECT 
      * 
    FROM 
      att 
    WHERE 
      uid = "f6c507fe-8928-4780-8b54-819611435755" 
    AND 
      (item_position <> '99' OR item_position IS NULL)
    AND 
      category IN('CAT1','CAT2');

thanks for the help!

Comment: @poldixd NULL <> '99' should be true, so that sounds strange but you can try adding a OR item_position is NULL.. just to check..

Comment: `NULL <> '99'` is `NULL`, which is effectively `FALSE`.